# Facebook API Sandbox account is asking for a valid payment method

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I've already setup my Facebook sandbox account. I've tested posting to the sandbox page and everything works. However, when trying to add and Ad it requires me to "Add a valid payment method to your ad account." I'm not sure why this is required since the Ads I will be running will not be live ads because it's running in a sandbox environment.

Does anyone have this problem and how did you solve it?

Tried connecting a real card and it doesn't work.